# The maze of letters - Clue Three

Tags: story, mazes, word-search

[<sub><---Previous clue</sub>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/a-long-but-relatively-easy-cipher-clue-two)

---

<sub>This is an entry in the 12<sup>th</sup> [Fortnightly Topic Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5084/fortnightly-topic-challenge-12-mazes?cb=1)</sub>

---

<sub>Inspiration from [@BMyGuest's puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37645/a-maze-ing-wordsearch)</sub>

---

After keying in your answer, the screen goes dark, and emits a BEEP!
You step back as a door swings in front of you, to reveal... a dark room. As you step across the threshold, the door swings shut with a *click*. A light turns on, slowly getting brighter. As your eyes adjust, you see that there is a wall in front of you, with a tiled floor visible through a doorway.
You turn around and try the door. Naturally, it's locked. What did you expect?
With no other options, you walk over to the doorway, and look at the floor. This is the sight that greets your eyes:

[image: better image]

On the far wall, there is a sign that says:

> **The third clue is hidden here. You must follow the path. Beware - if you step on a wrong tile, there are a lot of things thought up by a twelve year old that can kill you. You start at the tiles marked `Start here`, at the bottom left.**

---

**Hint:**

> I go diagonally exactly *once* in the puzzle. That time is in a crucial part of the path.

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38170/the-seemingly-innocent-message-clue-four)</sub>

Comment: Is the misalignment of the letters just a result of building the puzzle? (I've been there myself...) From what I've learnt: Using Google+ sheets like in the *solution* of my referenced puzzle is very useful for creating these puzzles. [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1th1GtVWP19uFHAnMsGKjO099OXUDH9W-gPc3k-sbg30/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Nice touch with the word in the top left tile :)

Comment: Here is a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dPWuZU24hsSJUpP7jz9KaWVbzLTg6lgZr29lLogMgk/edit?usp=sharing) and a [picture of better quality](http://i.stack.imgur.com/45xqX.png) if you want to use it. I hope I didn't make a mistake !

Comment: @Lordofdark fourth from top, nine from right - you wrote `y` instead of `u`.

Comment: @hypern Check out the bottom right also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with -

> I play the piano blindfolded and the clue is **silver** and you leave over there

Reasoning -

> It was mentioned that the one diagonal move would be at a crucial part of the path. I made this move on the word "clue" which is a key word.

Here is the path I took

> [image]

Comment: And for all those who are wondering: Yes, I can actually do that. :P