# The seemingly innocent message - Clue Four

Tags: story, steganography

<sub>[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38072/the-maze-of-letters-clue-three)</sub>

---

"*Whew,*" you exhale after making it through the maze alive. "That was tough."
After stopping to drink a bit of water from your backpack (did you forget that you had it? We mentioned it back in [Clue Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37993/a-long-but-relatively-easy-cipher-clue-two)), you start walking down thw drab, gray hallway. After about a minute and a half, you reach a door with a sign on it. And, of course, the keypad.
Resignedly, you start to read the sign, wishing that you weren't a *[redacted]*.

> Hello. Since you have done remarkably well surviving, we have presen*t* for you. It is: An eas*y* clue!
>   Perhap*s* you require an explanation. Previousl*y*, you entere*d* a maze, solved riddle*s*, and decoded ciphers. But now, everything you need to know is on this sign. Good luck!
>
> P.S.
>   Since we're being generous, you have three tries before it kills you. Good luck once again.

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38176/im-a-messenger-clue-five)</sub>

Comment: The backpack / water was in Clue 2, not 1 :)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Wow, someone noticed! :D Did you remember, or did you go check?

Comment: I'm late to the party, so I just read it recently. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> pepper

which we find by

> taking the first letter of each word in the blockquote with the last letter italicized