# I'm a messenger - Clue Five

Tags: riddle, story

<sub>[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38170/the-seemingly-innocent-message-clue-four)</sub>

---

The door swings open. You step inside, ready for another puzzle, be it cipher, maze, riddle, or mysterious signs. As you step into the room, which was *[redacted]*, a screen comes to life. On it is:

> I'm a messenger.

"Huh?" you say out loud. "What's that supposed to mean?"

As if in response to your question, the message on the screen changes.

> I'm much like Clue Three, but faster.

Quickly, you pull out paper and pencil from your backpack as the message changes again.

> My value is equal to a devoured 'E'.

...

> I'm also the first, but two is greater.

...

> And I'm used for both hot and cold.

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38726/some-messed-up-words-clue-six)</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're...

> Mercury.
> Mercury is a messenger god.
> Mercury is a metal, just like silver from clue 3.
> Its "value" - position on the periodic table - is 80 ("ate E").
> It's the first planet from the sun, but the second planet is bigger.
> And it's used in a thermometer to measure termperatures, both hot and cold. *(Thanks, GoodDeeds!)*

Comment: Perhaps that it is used in a thermometer to measure both hot and cold?

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Yep, I think that's it - added, thanks!

Comment: It's called *quicksilver*.