# Some messed up words - Clue Six

Tags: cipher, story

<sub>[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38176/im-a-messenger-clue-five)</sub>

---

The door swings open, to reveal *[redacted]* waiting there for you. Your jaw drops. You had no idea that this was so important, that *she* would get involved.

*[redacted]* steps towards you and hands you a piece of paper. It reads:

> ho an head ded ho if an ac

But you don't immediately focus on it. Instead, you focus on the *[redacted]* family leader, A *[redacted]* C *[redacted]*.
"What are you doing here?" you ask.
But instead of replying, she just smiled, and whispered, "You should go work on that now."
And stepping back, she disappears through a trapdoor.

You go to inspect the floor where she disappeared, but there's nothing. Those *[redacted]* scientists are good. You settle down on the floor in defeat, staring gloomily at the paper in your hand.

---

<sub>[Next clue-->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38880/the-rock-wall-of-letters-clue-seven)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And the answer is

> wormwood

All you have to do is to

> add up the alphabetical value of all letters in the word to produce a new letter.