# The rock wall of letters -- Clue Seven

Tags: story, word-search

<sup>[<--Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38726/some-messed-up-words-clue-six)</sup>

---

*Click*! The door swing open, to reveal a yellow room.

"It looks like a banana," you mutter as you walk in. Then you see the right wall. On it is something like a rock-climbing wall, only with letters instead of rocks. Each of the letters has a light underneath it, along with a button, presumably to select the letters of the answer. Cryptic instructions are printed to the right.

[image]

---

[<sub>Next clue---></sub>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40044/why-the-be-nice-policy-clue-eight)

Comment: I allowed this off-site. Don't worry.

Comment: My god, *what* are you making?  [REDACTED]?

Comment: @DanRussell No, we're making *[extra redacted]*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In the puzzle, find the words: take one letter below the first. The letters beneath the first letter of each word spells out **"barley"**

Comment: Was quick! Would it have been any harder if the words were out of order on the side?

Comment: Originally I wasn't sure if I was on the right track until the letters spelled the word.  Possibly scrambling the order of the letters in "barley" would be helpful.  I enjoyed it though!

Answer (score 8):

The answer is

> Barley

Because

> The puzzle is a word search. I have traced it out here - 
>  [image]
>  
>  I have circled the first letter of each word in blue, per the instructions. They are - 
>   **E B L A Y R**  which I 
>  unjumbled to 
>  BARLEY

Comment: It's not even scrambled. Go in the order of the words on the side.

Comment: You're right - didn't even catch that.