# Why the 'Be Nice' policy? - Clue Eight

Tags: cipher, story, steganography

[<sub><---Previous clue</sub>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38880/the-rock-wall-of-letters-clue-seven)

---

You push the buttons under the letters on the rock wall. Nothing happens for a moment. Then there is a rumbling noise.

gggrrrrrrrRRRRRRRR**RRRRRRRRRRR**

The rumbling stops. You look around your banana-colored room. Nothing seems to have changed, until you look directly behind you.

There is a picture there:

[image: qbagybbxnggurpbqrybbxngguvf]

It appears to be a printed-out screenshot of the ['Be Nice' policy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) on your favorite site, Puzzling.SE.

You turn it over. This is on the back:

<sub>liap-liap-lwb lwb-lwb-liap lwb-lwb-lwb-liap lwb-lwb-liap-lwb lwb-lwb-lwb-liap lwb-lwb-liap-lwb lwb-liap-liap-lwb lwb-lwb-lwb liap-liap-lwb-lwb liap-lwb-liap-lwb liap-lwb-liap-liap lwb-liap-lwb liap-liap-lwb lwb-liap-lwb liap-lwb-liap-liap lwb-lwb-lwb-liap lwb lwb lwb-liap-lwb liap-lwb-liap-liap lwb-liap-lwb lwb-lwb liap-lwb lwb-liap liap-liap-lwb lwb-lwb-liap-lwb liap-liap-lwb liap-lwb-lwb-lwb liap-lwb-liap-lwb lwb-liap-liap-liap liap-lwb liap-liap-lwb lwb-lwb-lwb-liap lwb-liap liap lwb-liap-lwb-lwb liap-lwb-lwb-lwb lwb-lwb-lwb-lwb lwb liap-liap-lwb lwb-lwb-lwb-liap liap-liap-lwb-lwb lwb-liap-lwb lwb-lwb-liap lwb-liap-lwb lwb lwb-liap-lwb</sub>

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40438/the-redacted-showing-off-their-skills-clue-nine)</sub>

Comment: Is the image supposed to be only thumbnail size or do you have a bigger version?

Comment: @Verence I put it in on that size intentionally, but if you remove the 'm' from the end of the image (click edit to see the link) you'll see a bigger version.

Comment: LuxxMiner did it (see comments to my answer). I just saw the bigger image.

Comment: -1: puzzles that are just multiple codes used over and over are not interesting.

Comment: @Mithrandir: Yes, I saw the answer. Red herrings are **also** bad puzzle design.

Comment: @Mithrandir Why is the picture with low resolution o.O

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is

> quartz
>  look at the bigger image and note all the missing letters. Almost all of them are in the beginning, but the "z" is in "lazy" in the middle.

The wrong way:

1:

> apply a ROT cipher and "liab" and "lwb" turn to "dash" and "dot". Morse code, obviously.

2:

> After decoding we get the following
>  GUVFVFPSZCYRGRYVEERYRINAGFGBCJNGVATLBHEGVZRURER

3:

> ROT13 gives us:
>  THISISCFMPLETELIRRELEVANTSTOPWATINGYOURTIMEHERE
>  Errors are just errors, nothing to do here.

Comment: Me too got till the 3rd and then thought this was a red herring and stopped....

Comment: yup, I got this too. accepted it as a herring and then tried to figure what in the world I was supposed to be doing... Still on that last part...

Comment: SPOILER: (Isn't worth a partial answer): When you edit the question you'll see the image has a description, convert it with ROT13 and you get *"dontlookatthecodelookatthis"* - So it definetely only has to do something with the image.

Comment: @LuxxMiner I was just about to post that :)

Comment: Oh, well spotted. Now what do we do with this keyword?

Comment: @JonathanAllan This is probably the final answer to this question. Since this question belongs to the series, we will need it later along with the other clues for the Final Puzzle.