# The [redacted] showing off their skills - Clue Nine

Tags: riddle, story

[<sub><---Previous clue</sub>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40044/why-the-be-nice-policy-clue-eight)

---

"*[redacted]*<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>" you say out loud. You've learned by now - sometimes you need to say it. Sure enough, something starts happening. The yellow walls turn green, as if they are only LED screens. The tiles under your feet change, becoming patterned with wolves. And finally, a voice begins to speak. It says:

> "You have three riddles to solve here. You must type the answer into the text box - *[You look around and don't see anything, so you assume that it'll show up later.]* - in order. the first riddle first, and the third third. Also, we're done being nice. **No mistakes**, or you die."

The voice clicks off, and the wall to your left ripples, and is now showing text on the green walls:

> I have something to do with penguins.
>   I am the father of many little girl's dreams.
>   I don't much like my new clothes.
>   At one point, my name started 'Ge'. At another, He'. Now - nothing.
>   I am always a man.

The one in front of you also:

> I have some negative connotations, as 
>   I am the embodiment of Chaos.
>   I scare small things.
>   I never worry about my toes.
>   Some call me Nadja. That's incorrect.

And finally the one on the right.

> You are not looking for me, but a synonym.
>   I look much like a pirates symbol.
>   I have a mythological relation to misery,
>   As well as half-horses.
>   I don't taste very good.

---

<sub><sup><sup>1</sup></sup> It's redacted because we don't want to spoil the fun. It's the answer to the last puzzle.</sub>

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40641/an-invisible-image-clue-ten)</sub>

Comment: How did you get the superscript in the text?

Comment: @Scratch---Cat - using either `<sub>text</sub>` or `<sup>`

Comment: And how did you change the text size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Full answer is**

> King Cobra Venom.

**First block gives**

> King

I have something to do with penguins.

> King penguin.

I am the father of many little girl's dreams.

> Little girls dream of being a princess, whose father is the king.

I don't much like my new clothes.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes (essentially a king...)

At one point, my name started 'Ge'. At another, He'. Now - nothing.

> The king of England has been "George" and "Henry", but now there is no king.

I am always a man.

> Otherwise she's a queen.

**The Second block gives**

> Cobra.

I have some negative connotations, as 
I am the embodiment of Chaos.

> E.g. Apep, the Egyptian deity who embodied Chaos and appeared as a snake.

I scare small things.

> Snakes eat (and, I would assume, frighten) small animals.

I never worry about my toes.

> Snakes have no feet.

Some call me Nadja. That's incorrect.

> *Naja* is the genus of the cobra. Perhaps, "Nadja" is incorrect, because the desired answer is "*Naja*", i.e. cobra.

**Third block gives**

> Venom.

You are not looking for me, but a synonym.

> The following clue will lead to poison, generally, but the desired answer is venom, a synonym of poison.

I look much like a pirates symbol.

> Skull and crossbones, common pirate symbol, is also the symbol for poison.

I have a mythological relation to misery,

> The Greek Achlys is connected to both poisons and misery.

As well as half-horses.

> The famous centaur Chiron was killed by a poisoned arrow.

I don't taste very good.

> Poison often doesn't taste good, nor does it *taste* good, as it kills the drinked.

Comment: King penguin? It's an *emperor* penguin.

Comment: @Mithrandir https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_penguin

Comment: Oh look. I made a reference without knowing it. I learned something!