# An invisible image - Clue Ten

Tags: visual, story

<sub>[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40438/the-redacted-showing-off-their-skills-clue-nine)</sub>

---

*[redacted] [redacted] [redacted] [redacted] [redacted] [redacted] [redacted]*

"Where?" you ask. "I don't see anything."

"That's the point - the image is *invisible*, doofus."

You don't appreciate being called a doofus, but you step forwards anyway and peer at the apparently empty screen in front of you. You turn around.

"What-"

The question dies in your throat as you realize that *[redacted]* is gone. With a sigh, you turn to the screen again:

[image: this image is invisible]

And then the second screen:

[image: also invisible]

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/uncle-sams-rebus-clue-eleven)</sub>

Comment: -1 because this puzzle is inherently impermanent.

Comment: @Will Whaddya mean? I'm leaving that in my profile. If not, I'll change the puzzle to a screenshot.

Comment: -1 both for @Will's reason and because the puzzle is uninteresting. It's just a long chain of QR codes.

Comment: @Deusovi I was going to add another step but I forgot. o_o I accept the DVs.

Comment: Its a different sort of puzzle but you over-used the QR Codes.

Comment: I saw a weird link in your profile signature and it says it's for Clue 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The images hide

> two QR codes, using transparency for "white" and white for "black":
>  [image][image]

They say

> `see my profile` and `all the way at the bottom`: in Mithrandir's profile there is [another link to another QR code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SriHL.png)

That one says

> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch3wd.png`, which is another link to a QR code.

*That* one says

> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpaTg.png`, which finally isn't a link to a QR code! It's a link to a regular bar code instead.

And that one finally says

> **Magnesium**.

Comment: Think I beat you to it by a few seconds! +1 though as you got the answer too

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I saw this complete answer before your grace period edit. ;)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: No, you didn't. I beat you to it, and then you edited your answer in the grace period. (Also, how does a barcode decode to something in bold? There's no syntax for that.)

Comment: @Deusovi I don't know my QR scanner just said magnesium and it was bold. Sorry if you beat me to it - I'll ask Mithrandir to transfer the accept if you all think that

Comment: Requested the accept to be transferred - don't know if @Mithrandir is still active though...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil No, I wasn't. I was asleep . :P And pinging me on the bottom of your answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

By saving the first image it comes up with a QR code:

[image: First QR Code]

By scanning it I get the information:

> See my profile

The second image gives us another QR:

[image]

Which gives us:

> All the way at the bottom

In his profile at the bottom it says:

> For Clue 10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SriHL.png

The link gives us:

[image: QR]

Which decodes to

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpaTg.png

Which gives us a barcode:

[image: barcode]

Which decodes to:

> **Magnesium** (In bold)