# Uncle Sam's rebus - Clue Eleven

Tags: story, rebus

[<sub><---Previous clue</sub>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40641/an-invisible-image-clue-ten)

---

After the easiness of the previous clue, you feel sure that the puzzles will start to get harder now. And the sign ahead seems to confirm that:

> This is the last easy puzzle you'll get. After this, you'll really start to stretch your brain. But first, Uncle Sam has a rebus for you. Speak the answer, and proceed.

[image: unclesam] [image: mantaray] [image: leg] [image: confused]

---

[<sub>Next clue---></sub>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40802/youll-need-thomas-jefferson-more-than-youll-expect-clue-twelve)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think its

> **Uranium**

1:

> "You" = U

2:

> "Ray" = Ra

3:

> "Knee" = Ni (Thanks @PartyHatPanda)

4:

> "Umm?" = Um