# You'll need Thomas Jefferson more than you'd expect - Clue Twelve

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

[<sub><---Previous clue</sub>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/uncle-sams-rebus-clue-eleven)

---

"*[redacted]*," you say aloud, following the instructions. And then a light shines through a crack in the wall, spreading until it shows an outline of a door. Then it swings open.

As the door opens, you get the light right in the face. As you squeeze your eyes shut, you hear the screech of a microphone, and a booming voice says:

> "You've done well so far. Good job. So now we have another Clue for you. Pay attention here. Use the Clues you have gotten so far. Doubtlessly you remember them. Every word here is important. Understand the power of two. More than you might expect you will need Thomas Jefferson. I know these sentences have been cryptic. It all adds up."

It's a good thing you have your phone always recording, so you play it back and listen again. The obvious place to start is with your list of existing clues: (this is the list of answers to the previous 11 clues)

> 1. honey
> 2. hydrogen
> 3. silver
> 4. pepper
> 5. mercury
> 6. wormwood
> 7. barley
> 8. quartz
> 9. king cobra venom
> 10. magnesium
> 11. uranium

Hint 1:

> There are two puzzles hidden in the text which have to be used together.

Hint 2:

> How many sentences are there?

Hint 3:

> Thomas Jefferson is both code and key.

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45923/clue-thirteen-add-two-more-and-youll-have-me)</sub>

Comment: I'm assuming Scimonster is another account of @Mithrandir?

Comment: @gtwebb No, we've just arranged off-site to share this puzzle series.

Comment: Do we need to solve the previous ones before solving this one?

Comment: @FoldedChromatin You just need the answers, which i have conveniently provided in a spoiler tag.

Comment: So, did this story just die? I'm sad, I wanted to figure out who [redacted] was!

Comment: @Tumbler41 Solve the clue and the series can continue!

Comment: I'd be doing this puzzle if I didn't have to code in Scratch to make another puzzle...

Comment: Does "Understand the power of two" just refer to what you've said in Hint 1, or is there more meaning than that to this sentence?

Comment: @randal'thor There's more to it than that.

Comment: @Mithrandir Many cough couches. By the way, what Scratch username do you have? I know who Scimonster is on Scratch and GitHub, but I do not recognize your username.

Comment: @Mithrandir Next clue coming soon?

Comment: @Mithrandir Patience is hard!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The clue about Thomas Jefferson tells us that the solution must involve

> the [Jefferson disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson_disk) encryption method.

We also notice, as suggested by Hint 2, that

> the number of sentences in the message is 11, exactly the same as the number of solutions found so far. This suggests that each sentence corresponds to one of these previous solutions.

Putting these two ideas together, I think we're going to need

> an 11-disc Jefferson encryption.

So we still need three things in order to find the plaintext.

- The **ciphertext**.

  > This is probably hidden within the 11-sentence message somewhere, and an obvious guess is to take the first letter of every sentence: **YGSPUDEUMII**.
- The **key** (i.e. the ordering of the discs).

  > I.e. the ordering of the discs. According to Hint 3 this is "Jefferson", but I'm not sure how to turn that 9-letter word into an ordering of 11 discs. Jefferson was the 3rd president of the USA, but that only gives us an ordering of the 3rd disc, not all 11.
- The **discs themselves**.

  > We still need to know how the alphabet is actually scrambled on each disc! My guess is that we use the previous solutions: e.g. "hydrogen" gives the alphabet as HYDROGENABCFIJKLMPQSTUVWXZ or "wormwood" gives it as WORMDABCEFGHIJKLNPQSTUVXYZ.

  Or, following the OP's [hint](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40802/youll-need-thomas-jefferson-more-than-youd-expect-clue-twelve/42067#comment125014_42067) that "it might not be a standard Jefferson wheel", let's use the words themselves, to get the following 'discs':

  > `HONEY`
  >  `HYDROGEN`
  >  `SILVER`
  >  `PEPPER`
  >  `MERCURY`
  >  `WORMWOOD`
  >  `BARLEY`
  >  `QUARTZ`
  >  `KINGCOBRAVENOM`
  >  `MAGNESIUM`
  >  `URANIUM`

Ignore the key for the moment, since the letters YGSPUDEUMII already appear in exactly the right words in the right order. Arranging the wheels to the right position, we get:

> ```
>          HONEY
>       ENHYDROG
>         ILVERS
>         EPPERP
>        RYMERCU
>       WORMWOOD
>         YBARLE
>         ARTZQU
> KINGCOBRAVENOM
>      UMMAGNESI
>        UMURANI
> ```

Then we decrypt using a step size of 3 (since Jefferson was the 3rd president), i.e. shifting 3 letters backwards on each wheel, to get the 'plaintext'

> ODVPMWATENR.

At some point we'll also need to use powers of 2 and everything adding up, as suggested by the hints in the message. And at the end of the day, the final answer is likely to be

> WATER

as [discovered by dcfyj](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40805/5373).

So we'd like to be able to pick the 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, and 11th letters from the 'plaintext' we now have, but I couldn't see where the motivation comes from to do so.

After getting help in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair), I realised what the justification is meant to be for the final step:

> in the 11-sentence message, "Every word here is important" and "It all adds up" tells us to count the total number of words in that message: 61. Then "Understand the power of two" tells us to put that 61 into binary representation as 00000111101. Pick only the letters corresponding to 1's, and we get the final solution WATER as expected.

---

**Feedback section**

Next time, please make the required steps a *little* clearer :-) There's a lot to do in this puzzle, with absolutely no confirmation (other than hints received from the OP) until the very last step. I wouldn't have got this at all if I hadn't known (thanks to dcfyj) what the solution was going to be; nor would I have been able to justify the final step if I hadn't got some help in chat. The ideal multi-layer puzzle has some sort of confirmation at each step that the solver is on the right track; I realise this isn't always possible, but it's at least something to strive for.

Comment: You're now well on the path to solving it.

Comment: But it might not be a standard Jefferson wheel.

Comment: I was originally skeptical of your ciphertext, but after noticing that every letter appears in the appropriate clue I think you may actually be right! :)

Comment: @Tumbler41 my thought exactly!

Comment: @rand you're back!  It's amazing how you still manage to be an incredibly active user and mod on another site.  Where do you find the hours?

Comment: Nicely done! Could you elaborate on the "step size of three?" I see all the 'plaintext' letters in the discs, but I can't find a pattern to how you chose them.

Comment: @Tumbler41 I edited the depiction of the wheels to make it clearer, and added an extra clause about the step size of 3.

Comment: Ah! Right justification! I was using left justification. Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 2):

A wild guess:

> There are 11 sentences, so I map each to a previous answer.
>   The sentences in the clue contain this many words each:
>  5,2,8,3,8,4,5,5,10,7,4
>
>
> The text says "Understand the power of two." So, which sentences have word counts that are powers of 2?
>
> Sentence 2= 2^1 = Hydrogen 
> Sentence 3= 2^3 = Silver 
> Sentence 5= 2^3 = Mercury 
> Sentence 6= 2^1 = Wormwood
> Sentence 11= 2^2 = Uranium 
>
> The text says "you will need Thomas Jefferson" who was the 3rd, so we narrow it down to sentences with the 3rd power of 2, which leaves
>
> Sentence 3= Silver 
> Sentence 5=  Mercury 
>
> "It all adds up," so we combine silver and mercury to get:
> **Quicksilver**

Comment: Nice try, you're on the right track. You need the power of two of something else though. Same with "it all adds up". Thomas Jefferson is indeed the third president, but you'll need him for more than that. ;)

Comment: Could the power of two be referring to Morse code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer may be:

> **water** which is the next item on the list
>  or possibly *The Cahill Fire Painting* itself

I've come to this conclusion by:

> first googling "thomas jefferson honey uranium"
>  which gave me [this page](http://39clues.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jefferson_Puzzle)
>  which in turn had the list with all the previous clues on it.
>
>  The answers from the past 11 puzzles and the one in my answer can all be found within a painting made from 10 cards which are found in a 10 book series called *The 39 clues*.

Comment: I recommend you try solving the puzzle instead of trying to find the answer with Google.

Comment: @Scimonster I googled in order to find a correlation between the items and found that webpage...

Comment: Everything you need is in the puzzle itself, perhaps drawing on some common knowledge as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could possibly be:

> helium

Reasoning:

> There are 2 mentions of the word "here" in the Clue. Since it's a voice, it could have meant "hear", combining two gets "hear hear" which is commonly heard in a congress. Thomas Jefferson was a member of the 2nd Continental Congress, along with John Adams. John Adams (the 2nd president) had Thomas Jefferson as his Vice President (or 2nd in command). His name also loosely rhymes with "Join Atoms". Our sun combines 2 hydrogen (the 2nd answer) to produce helium. Helium is commonly used in balloons to "add up" (lift).

Comment: Nice try, but that's not it. I see you haven't used "Every word here is important."