# Add two more and you'll have me - Clue Thirteen

Tags: riddle, story

<sub>[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40802/youll-need-thomas-jefferson-more-than-youd-expect-clue-twelve)</sub>

---

The light shuts off, and you are left in the dark - for a moment. Then you notice a glow coming from the tiled floor. You peer down to have a better look. In a 3x2 space, the six tiles say:

> I'm essential to life
> But maybe not quite.
>
> This is number thirteen
> But add two more and you'll have me.
>
> I'm not bright
> But I still have some light.
>
> I don't have a lamb
> But I am inside one.
>
> If you follow my lure
> You may need a cure.
>
> I am red and white, but not blue.
> Instead, I'm black and violet - scarlet too.

Each of letters is glowing slightly white, with a glass covering above the letters. Next to them, there is that familiar keyboard for the answer. You reach over it and type...

---

<sub>[Next clue --->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45950/clue-fourteen-the-great-fall)</sub>

Comment: I'd forgotten about this series.

Comment: @dcfyj Well, hopefully it will be finished eventually...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> Phosphorus?

I'm essential to life
But maybe not quite.

> Phosphates are part of DNA and such

This is number thirteen
But add two more and you'll have me.

> Phosphorus is 15 on the Periodic Table

I'm not bright
But I still have some light.

> Phosphorescence is a glow, but usually not bright.

I don't have a lamb
But I am inside one.

> Uraguay apparently bred glowing sheep

If you follow my lure
You may need a cure.

> Phosphorus is poisonous

I am red and white, but not blue.
Instead, I'm black and violet - scarlet too.

> Red and White are the most common Phosphorus allotropes, but violet black and scarlet also exist

Another hint:

> The keys are glowing

Comment: What about the rest of the lines? You got it right, but let's try to get all of them... :P

Comment: Mary had a little lamb...

Comment: Get Felica a Job.

Comment: (Those are hints...)