# The great fall - Clue Fourteen

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

<sub>[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45923/clue-thirteen-add-two-more-and-youll-have-me)</sub>

---

<sup>*New: Now with **illustrations!***</sup>

---

You key in your answer. Then you hear a click. Aghhhhh.... the ground beneath you suddenly isn't there anymore.

[image: falling]

You hit the ground with a *crash*, in a dark room. Gingerly, you get to your feet, hoping for no broken bones. Nothing appears to be broken, but you're going to have some spectacular bruises by the end of this gauntlet.

[image: standing]

Suddenly, you're blinded by a light turning on. The light isn't *that* bright, but it's bright enough compared to the darkness that it blinds you temporarily. As you squeeze your eyes shut, you ruefully acknowledge that it seems as if that's been happening a lot lately...

[image: light]

As your eyes adjust, you see that you are in a tunnel. High above, you can't even see where you fell through. However, there appears to be some sort of path that you're standing on, but you don't know which way to go. You look around to see if there's any indication, and then you see it - some words with an arrow.

[image: follow the trail and you will see / you will soon discover me]

You follow the trail in the direction indicated by the arrow for about ten minutes (out of the reach of the light), when you catch sight of a wall in front of you. After a couple more minutes, you come up to the wall. You can faintly see something scratched onto the wall, but it's too... dark...

[image: qr code]

It appears to be a QR code, but it's too dark for your phone, which has miraculously survived your fall, to scan. Naturally, the light picks that moment to go on, blinding you yet again. But now it's light enough for your phone to pick it up...

[image: qr code 2]

---

**What is the Clue?**

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45992/dance-a-jigsaw-clue-fifteen)</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The QR code decodes to:

> Good job you've reached the end of me/ now go back and you will see/ that there is more hidden here/ go look have no fear/ you will have to go in more/ don't worry there's no gore.

So,

> We observe that clicking on each of the images leads to another more detailed version of itself. Each image has a hidden letter, in a faint colour.

They are,

> C,
>  O (though it looks more like an upside down D to me),
>  P,
>  P again,
>  E,
>  R.

Images, with the hidden elements zoomed and circled:

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Therefore the clue is:

> COPPER.

Comment: Even looking for them, and right AT them, I find these really hard to see :)  Good job

Answer (score 4):

**Partial Answer**

QR code decodes to

> Good job you've reached the end of me / now go back and you will see / that there is more hidden here / go look have no fear / you will have to go in more / don't worry there's no gore

Or, reformatted:

> Good job you've reached the end of me
>  now go back and you will see
>  that there is more hidden here
>  go look have no fear
>  you will have to go in more
>  don't worry there's no gore