# Dance a Jigsaw - Clue Fifteen

Tags: story, jigsaw-puzzle

<sub>[<<---First clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/i-am-an-expression-of-a-deer-mint-clue-one)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45950/the-great-fall-clue-fourteen)</sub>

---

Now that you had your clue, you have a feeling that it might be time to get out. You look around for a door, and... don't see one. However, you do see something that you hadn't noticed before - a rectangle with pieces lying next to it. You go to take a closer look.

On closer inspection, it is revealed to be a jigsaw puzzle. However, it doesn't have the regular edges - all of them have smooth edges. It looks like this will take a while...

[image: one] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image: 14] [image: 15] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46230/the-word-web-clue-sixteen)</sub>

Comment: why the downvotes???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this ->

> [image]
>  [Image Source](http://www.tayari.co.il/Product.php?serial=602000)

And here's the label of the Jigsaw Drink

> [image]
>  Text -> **"Old Dutch Apple Cider Vinegar"**

So the Clue is

> Vinegar

Comment: Well, to be frank, I did spend a little time on Paint. But eventually found the words to Google :)

Comment: Do you mean I should create the image out of the scrambled images?

Comment: @Mithrandir- Hope that works for you. I am not good with image editing. :D

Comment: For what it's worth, the solved jigsaw looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFXJM.png. (The things one does just for the sake of procrastination.)

Comment: @MOehm- I will happily take down my answer if you want to add yours. I was not sure if solving the jigsaw is the only solution here and hence took a short-cut. BTW, well done with the final image. :)

Comment: There isn't anything in the final jigsaw that isn't in the googled image, so your solution is the clever one. Mine just goes to show that I have too much time on my hands.