# The Word Web - Clue Sixteen

Tags: word, story, english

<sub>[<<---First clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/i-am-an-expression-of-a-deer-mint-clue-one)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45992/dance-a-jigsaw-clue-fifteen)</sub>

---

<sub>Inspiration from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40018/clue-web-1-lets-start).</sub>

---

<sub>A lot of credit to [@Scimonster](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4456/scimonster) here; we created this puzzle together.</sub>

---

"Aha!" you exclaim, finally spotting the door - it's an almost invisible gray door against the wall. You head over there, expecting to find a challenge - and you aren't disappointed. Inscribed above the door is a strange sign:

[image: doorwithcluewebimage]

Next to the door is a plaque. On the plaque it says:

> Remember the Clue Web, on your favorite website, posted by the renowned puzzler Brent Hackers? Excellent, because now's your chance to solve one! Maybe you don't remember how to to play. (Even though it was an awesome puzzle.) Mithrandir, here are the rules: Begin by taking one group of four words. Each word in the group can be connected to another word, which is not here. Repeat for the next three groups. Then, you take those four words, and find the word that connects those three. (Hopefully, there will be only one.) After that, you'll have your precious Clue. Terrific, no?
>
> **Group 1**
> gain, fee, no, point
> tomato, egg, green, fruit
> gong, liberty, Alexander, curve
> floor, ballroom, around, modern
>
> **Group 2**
> white, midnight, cat, pitch
> lining, bullet, tongue, sterling
> key, horns, caps, hair
> cross, swallowing, broad, wound
>
> **Group 3**
> red, oven, ton, wall
> roll, skipping, baby, chair
> zebra, true, earn, stars
> know, opinion, matter, ground
>
> **Group 4**
> stroke, pack, scratch, log
> side, get, loud, right
> fast, thunder, rod, storm
> fates, pigs, bears, witches

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46702/the-strange-notebook-clue-seventeen)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Group 1

> ***bar (@Aethon)***
>  **entry** gain, fee, no, point   (@Sconibulus)
>  **salad** tomato, egg, green, fruit   (@Sconibulus)
>  **bell** gong, liberty, Alexander, curve
>  **dance** floor, ballroom, around, modern

Group 2

> ***smith***
>  **black** white, midnight, cat, pitch
>  **silver** lining, bullet, tongue, sterling
>  **lock** key, horns, caps, hair
>  **sword** cross, swallowing, broad, wound

Group 3

> ***solid***
>  **brick** red, oven, ton, wall
>  **rock** roll, skipping, baby, chair
>  **stripes** zebra, true, earn, stars
>  **truth** know, opinion, matter, ground

Group 4

> ***strike (@Sconibulus)***
>  **back** stroke, pack, scratch, log
>  **out** side, get, loud, right
>  **lightning** fast, thunder, rod, storm
>  **three** fates, pigs, bears, witches

And based on work by @Sconibulus and comments by @Aethon, the final group is

> ***gold (@Aethon)*** (**bar**, **smith**, **solid**, **strike**)

So the clue is

> Gold

Comment: Correct! An accept will have to wait until Mithrandir comes online though.

Answer (score 5):

Group 1:

> Bar: (@Aethon)
>  gain, fee, no, point: Entry
>  tomato, egg, green, fruit: Salad
>  gong, liberty, Alexander, curve: Bell
>  floor, ballroom, around, modern: Dance

Group 2:

> Smith:
>  white, midnight, cat, pitch: Black
>  lining bullet tongue sterling: Silver
>  key, horns, caps, hair: Lock
>  cross, swallowing, broad, wound: Sword

Group 3:

> Solid:
>  red, oven, ton, wall: Brick
>  roll, skipping, baby, chair: Rock  (tmpearce)
>  zebra, true, earn, stars: Stripes
>  know, opinion, matter, ground: Fact

Group 4:

> Strike:
>  stroke, pack, scratch, log: Back
>  side, get, loud, right: Out
>  fast, thunder, rod, storm: Lightning
>  fates, pigs, bears, witches: Three

And the final answer is:

> Gold (@Aethon)

Comment: Since you put partial groups in, I added mine as well. Feel free to take a look. I like your word for group 4.

Comment: I think the final answer is going to be tbyq (rot13), and the first group is actually one (rot13).  I still can't figure out group 3 line 4, but I think the overall group 3 will need to be ebnq (rot13).

If I should be submitting this as a separate answer instead of a comment, please let me know.  Most of my guesses were built off of yours, though, so it seemed better to let you use them.

Comment: @Aethon The header I have for group 3 would fit with you final answer...

Comment: @tmpearce Ah!  And that makes sense for group 3 line 4, too!

Comment: Oh yeah, that works great, thanks @Aethon

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

Group 1

> gain, fee, no, point
>  tomato, egg, green, fruit
>  gong, liberty, Alexander, curve -- BELL
>  floor, ballroom, around, modern

Group 2 (tmpearce)

> white, midnight, cat, pitch -- BLACK
>  lining, bullet, tongue, sterling -- SILVER
>  key, horns, caps, hair -- LOCK
>  cross, swallowing, broad, wound -- SWORD?

Group 3

> red, oven, ton, wall -- BRICK
>  roll, skipping, baby, chair
>  zebra, true, earn, stars -- STRIPE???
>  know, opinion, matter, ground

Group 4

> stroke, pack, scratch, log -- BACK
>  side, get, loud, right
>  fast, thunder, rod, storm -- LIGHTNING
>  fates, pigs, bears, witches

Comment: Can you please spoilerify your answer?

Comment: I'm on my phone. It would be nice if you edited for me though.