# The strange notebook - Clue Seventeen

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story

<sub>[<<---First clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/37784/25966)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46230/25966)</sub>

---

The door swings open. You step through, and it closes - *thud* - behind you.

You look around. You are in what appears to be a normal living room, with some chairs, couches, and a coffee table. On the coffee table is a red notebook, marked simply **Clue**.

[image: cluenotebook]

You open it to the first page. There is a very strange sentence:

> Your Question is Finally loaded.

[image]
It looks like it *could* have come from puzzling.SE, talking about *Questions*, but...

You shrug.

You look at the next page:

> [image: ugly]

*My, what an ugly emoticon*, you think.

Baffled, you head to the next page:

> 9 days forth, the ghouls depart.
>   Xanter must be protected **at all costs**.
>   87 wounded - must return.
>   t'Was dead.
>   o'Toole traitor - he betrayed us to the Yalshikites.

You close the notebook, baffled by the strange pages. On the back cover, you see one more thing:

> C? y have you done this? Zelda will usurp! Caster will kill me! Help!

---

Can you help find out what's going on here, and find the Clue?

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46876/clue-18-should-this-be-on-stack-overflow)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the back cover...

> Taking the first letter of each sentence gets https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyZCH.png

Which is

> [image]

so

> 't'

Doing the same for the other page gets

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X8to.png

Which is

> [image]

so

> 'v'

There is also (Thanks @DisplayName!)

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQiFl.png

which is

> [image]

and by clicking on the 'What on Earth' line you get

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcJCK.png

which is

> [image]

and also (Thanks again @DisplayName) in the top right off the emoji link

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzcSU.png

which is

> [image]

Giving

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/glmvt.png

Which is

> [image]

And *that* is ROT 13 for

> 'lunch on one of saturns moons'

To which the answer, thanks @Scconibulus, is

> IODINE - IO being a moon, DINE being to have lunch

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcJCK.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X8to.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyZCH.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQiFl.png (Presumably one missing)

Comment: And https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzcSU.png

Comment: Which is https://i.stack.imgur.com/glmvt.png

Comment: Can't type quick enough!

Comment: @Mithrandir is the final answer similar to 'breakfast on one of jupiter's stars' or is there another step?

Comment: If you figure out what that's supposed to mean, that's it.

Comment: ...I was stuck on ideas for a puzzle. Don't worry, #18 going to be good - I came up with the idea and Sci made it, so... :P

Comment: Oh so is it a cryptic clue @Mithrandir?

Comment: I've never been entirely sure what a cryptic clue *is*, so... I have no idea. Possibly.