# A Cryptic Clue Nineteen

Tags: story, steganography, cryptic-clues

<sub>[<<---First clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/i-am-an-expression-of-a-deer-mint-clue-one)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46876/clue-18-should-this-be-on-stack-overflow)</sub>

---

You close th*e* computer and sta*n*d up. You now have 18 clues. *Only [re*d*acted] more to go!*, you think.

You head to the door and try to open *i*t. It didn't open. What did you expect? Instead, there's a place for a password. U*n*derneath is a plaque:

> So. Off on your hunt again, are you? For you to be able to pass this door, you must prove that you are worthy. *T*he previous puzzles do not count for this.
>   <sub>?</sub>
>   Now, please take a moment and search - there's something here. Over, under, up, down, r*i*ght, left - somewhere. This part isn't hard.
>
> Finally found it? Ready your brain - this will be hard. On this plaque, there is your Clu*e*. Many have searched and failed.
>   <sub>A</sub>
>   Where is the Clue? On what part? Ready? Mark!
>   <sub>(4)</sub>

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47128/the-scrambled-riddle-clue-twenty)</sub>

Comment: @Mithrandir When will the next challenge come out?

Comment: @KritixiLithos whenever I make it... Dunno. Depend on whether I have a good idea or not.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first letters say

> SOFT NOT FROM WORM

and the italics say

> *end in tie*

So the cryptic clue might be

> **Soft? Not from a worm. End in tie (4)**

To which @Sconibulus suggested the answer

> SILK

as

> 'Soft as silk', a 'SILKWORM' is *not* a worm, it's a caterpillar. And then we have a silk tie.

Comment: That was *fast*.