# The scrambled riddle - Clue Twenty

Tags: riddle, story, knowledge

<sub>[<<---First clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/i-am-an-expression-of-a-deer-mint-clue-one)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46930/a-cryptic-clue-nineteen)</sub>

---

You walk through the door. Everything is dark. You walk forwards slowly. Then, suddenly, you slip on something, just as the light goes on. "*Aghhhh!*" you scream, slipping and falling, bruising your elbow. Dust fills the air.

When the dust clears, you see that there were letters on the floor, obviously in some sort of form. However, when you slipped, you knocked the letters everywhere. Some of them are still there, but there are a lot that were knocked out. At least three have been crushed to powder.

```
A jo   d wo    we  s me,  eadi y.
S mi   ally, I'm rat  r b  ter, al  ough o ce I was va  ed gr   ly.
I     live in your c   net, but  o  mi ht not  no .
Kn e? Ho ? I ju t l♡   the expl  nati n and the d er.
If yo  re a    tish   ther. . I mi  t be t ere, u   en. W    am I?
```

You gather up the letters that you found:

`h.siyauneerteycwigmemayatbuworaibkieilebveaeultn'oasmehghhntet`

You groan. Now you have to fix the riddle, in addition to solving it...

---

## Hint

> You look over at the wall and notice something scratched into it. You lean closer. It seems to say 'Kritot 6a'. What could that mean?

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47416/the-bakery-clue-twenty-one)</sub>

Comment: There is a love heart after an l. Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil yep

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Completed riddle:**

```
A joined woman wears me, beadily.
Semitically, I'm rather bitter, although once I was valued greatly.
I may live in your cabinet, but you might not know.
Knee? How? I just love the expleenation and the dyer.
If you're a british mother... I might be there, unseen. What am I?
```

Thanks to Volatility for help in chat.

The answer is

> Myrrh

```
A joined woman wears me, beadily
```

> Fragrant "myrrh beads"  are traditionally worn by married women in Mali as multiple strands around the hips.

```
Semitically, I'm rather bitter, although once I was valued greatly.
```

> Myrrh is considered bitter and was once valued greatly.

```
I may live in your cabinet, but you might not know.
```

> Myrrh is used in toothpaste

```
Knee? How? I just love the expleenation and the dyer.
```

> Knee? How? Sound like Ni Hao - Chinese for hello. There was a heart in love, ekSPLEENation and liver from dyer. In Chinese medication it has a special efficacy on the heart, liver and spleen

```
If you're a british mother... I might be there, unseen. What am I?
```

> A british mother is a MUMMY, and myrrh was used in mummification.

Comment: @Mithrandir- If you are referring to **Knee? How?** its 4th line. If it's third line, the first two words are **I may**

Comment: @Mithrandir Ahh, I guess it worked this time ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial:**

```
A joined woman wears me, beadily.  
Semitically, I'm rather bitter, although once I was valued greatly.  
I may live in your cabinet, but  you  might not  know .  
Knee? How? I just l♡ve the expleenation and the dyer.  
If you're a british mother. . I might be there, unseen. What am I?
```

Comment: Not bitter, not explanation. See chat

Comment: Nope, not worm. Not readily. Not explanation. Yes bitter @BeastlyGerbil

Comment: Nearly. I've solved it (Mithrandir confirms) see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial: Attempt to reconstruct riddle**

Placing back some of the letters:

```
A jo   d wo    we  s me, readily.
S mi   ally, I'm rather b  ter, although once I was valued greatly.
I     live in your cabinet, but you might not know.
Kn e? Ho ? I just l♡ve the explanation and the d er.
If you're a    tish   ther... I might be there, u   en. What am I?
```

Letters left: `aabbceeeeeiiiimmmnnorswyy`

Comment: its not explanation. Mithrandir said so in chat. And it's not readily either