# The bakery - Clue Twenty One

Tags: cipher, story, steganography, imgur-maze

<sub>[<<---First clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/i-am-an-expression-of-a-deer-mint-clue-one)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47128/the-scrambled-riddle-clue-twenty)</sub>

<sub>(No, I haven't just gone and jeopardized Mithrandir's entire series, I have been given permission by him to do clue 21.)</sub>

*<sub>A note from @Mithrandir: I have given explicit permission for @BeastlyGerbil to post this, and gave him the answer to encode. If you want to post one, ping @Mithrandir in chat and we'll talk.</sub>*

---

Before you can even have a moment to celebrate solving the previous clue, a trapdoor opens beneath you and you fall into darkness. You scream before opening your eyes to find you are no longer falling but landed on a padded floor. The trapdoor is just above your head but just out of reach.

You look around and are confronted by a picture which on first appearance seems to be levitating in front of you, though you suspect there are wires, suspending it from the ceiling, hidden in the darkness. You move forward to scrutinize the picture more.

[image]

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47548/the-word-web-of-horror-clue-twenty-two)</sub>

Comment: Is the misspelling of "confectionery" deliberate?

Comment: @randal'thor ack no. My app that I use to put text on doesn't have spell check... I can edit quite easily though

Comment: You should use your brain to spell check, not an app :-)

Comment: @Techidiot anything in the text that is wrong is a typo, thanks :P

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madrigal) has to do with anything ...

Comment: @randal'thor not with the puzzle. Mithrandir requested I put it in. Apparently it's for the metapuzzle at the end.

Comment: @randal'thor It has something to do with the series, but is not relevant to this puzzle. if you look at the others, you'll see that I've started adding them because I forgot at first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Community Wiki from OP with complete answer:

By clicking on the image we get

> [image]

To get the next image

> Take the coloured letters and put them in the order of the colours on the tarp - oeEzg

Which is

> [image]

This is

> representing binary. 8 ball pool = 8 bit binary. For the number of the ball on the table, $n$, the $n$<sup>th</sup> byte is a 1. For instance, if only ball 8 was on the table, that would represent 00000001.

So

> 1. Balls 23568 = 01101101 = m
> 2. Balls 2356 = 01101100 = l
> 3. Balls 2358 = 01101001 = i
> 4. Balls 238 = 01100001 = a
> 5. Balls 2468 = 01010101 = U

Giving

> mliaU

which is

> [image]

This is

> Morse code - a pencil being a dash and a marble a dot.

If part of the image is higher up then it represents capitalization.

This gives

> TpV8N

Giving

> [image]

The

> Xs here are braille.

They give

> ydCpo

Which is

> [image]

Sign language for

> bTDJk

which is the final image

> [image]

The answer is

> MACE

which is hidden

> My enig**ma ce**ases now, - end of enigma and start of ceases
> **M**y l**a**st ra**c**e her**e**,  - 1st of first word, 2nd of second etc.
> Just a s**ec, am**ple brow, - backwards in ample and sec
> Giv**e** fa**c**e e**a**ten **m**are. - backwards 4th of first, 3rd of second etc.
> **M**aybe **a**ll, **c**anned **e**ar? - First letters
> Fro**m** se**a**, magi**c** her**e**. - Last letters

Answer (score 10):

Working from [Sid's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47422/25957), and taking into account that:

> it's [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille), with X representing the dots. The upper tic-tac-toe game represent an upper letter, we get:
>  y, d, C, p, o

New image!

> [image]

which is:

> Sign language, and this gives us: b, T, D, J, k

So, another image!

> [image]

And we find the final solution hidden in this riddle:

> the word **mace**
>
>  In the first line:
>  My enig**ma ce**ases now
>  In the second line, we take the 1st letter of the first word, the 2nd letter of the 2nd word, etc:
>  **M**y l**a**st ra**c**e her**e**
>  Reversed in the third line:
>  Just a s**ec, am**ple brow
>  We take the 1st letter of the 4th word, the 2nd letter of the 3rd line, etc in the fourth line:
>  Giv**e** fa**c**e e**a**ten **m**are.
>  First letter of each word in the fifth line:
>  **M**aybe **a**ll, **c**anned **e**ar?
>  And the last letters of the last line:
>  Fro**m** se**a**, magi**c** her**e**.

Answer (score 8):

### Partial answer

The tarp

> has the colours yellow, green, cyan, magenta, orange, in that order. Taking the corresponding letters with those colours (o, e, E, z, g) yields the following imgur image:
>
>  [image]

Comment: Good start, keep going

Comment: "Taking the corresponding letters with those colours" - wait, what? How do those letters correspond to those colours?

Comment: @randal'thor check the top of the tarp. Then look closely at the letters

Comment: Each table's balls are ROT13(ovanel olgrf)

Answer (score 8):

### Partial answer

The tables in the image [Volatility found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47418) are

> binary encoded ASCII, each ball being a `1` bit (if we number the bits in a byte from left-to-right, i.e., MSB = 1 through LSB = 8) - for example the first table is `01101101` = `m`

decoding them as such yields the URL to the next image

> [image: mliaU]

Comment: Morse code. Ball is dot. Pencil is Dash.

Comment: Yep! 8 ball pool = 8 bit binary

Answer (score 8):

Here's the third part:

> Pencil is Dash. Ball is Dot. Whichever is upper is Uppercase. So we get TpV8N:
>  [image]