# A reprieve from the brain-stretching - Clue Twenty Three

Tags: riddle, story

<sub>[<<---First clue](/q/37784)

[<--Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47548/the-word-web-of-horror-clue-twenty-two)</sub>

---

You push the door open. You look around, expecting another hard puzzle like the previous one.

You look at the floor. It says:

> In recognition of you work, we would like to award you a Nob... sorry, wrong speech.
>
> In recognition of your work, we are giving you an easy puzzle. Just a plain, simple, undisguised riddle. Hope you're happy. The next one's impossible.
>
> The first part of me:
>   Apparently, I’m very lovely… but I’m also dangerous.
>   If you try to hug me, you may be pricked.
>   Don’t make me blush – I’m red enough.
>   But I’m also as pale as a ghost.
>   And yellow as the sun.
>
> The second part of me:
>   Bloody? Me? Well, yes.
>   But that was a long time ago.
>   At least I wasn’t like my father!
>   I am going to have mutton for dinner.
>   This livestock is really getting on my nerves.
>
> Add us together, and what do you see?
>   This is the answer to Clue 23!

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47777/portraits-and-quotes-clue-twenty-four)</sub>

Comment: I was originally planning on hiding this riddle in a maze, but my computer died and lost my work and I didn't feel like doing all of that work again, so viola. An easy puzzle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see

> ROSEMARY

*Apparently, I’m very lovely… but I’m also dangerous.

If you try to hug me, you may be pricked.*

> Lots of people like roses, but their thorns are painful to touch.

*Don’t make me blush – I’m red enough.

But I’m also as pale as a ghost.

And yellow as the sun.*

> Roses come in red, white and yellow.

*Bloody? Me? Well, yes.
But that was a long time ago.*

> Mary I of England is known as ["Bloody Mary"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_I_of_England).

*At least I wasn’t like my father!*

> [Henry VIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_VIII_of_England) ordered the execution of many people.

*I am going to have mutton for dinner.

This livestock is really getting on my nerves.*

> Reference to the poem [Mary had a little lamb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Had_a_Little_Lamb).

Comment: Yep, I knew this one was easy. +1

Comment: Mustn't stretch the brain too much !

Comment: I was actually thinking of the 4th one. +1 for fast response

Comment: (Roses don't have thorns)

Comment: Most do, last I heard... @Strawberry

Comment: Nope - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorns,_spines,_and_prickles

Comment: Oh all right @Strawberry, you win this one :)