# Portraits and quotes - Clue Twenty Four

Tags: cipher, cryptic-clues, quote

<sub>[<<---First clue](/q/37784)

[<--Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47772/5373)</sub>

---

<sub>*A note from @Mithrandir: I have given explicit permission for @Randal'Thor to post this, and gave him the answer to encode. If you want to post one, ping @Mithrandir in chat and we'll talk.*</sub>

---

*[redacted]*, you say, and instantly a panel slides aside in the wall in front of you to reveal a new puzzle.

Feeling buzzed after your quick solution of the last clue, but also worried that the next one will be devilishly hard, you approach the wall and stare at it in bewilderment. All you see are four images:

[image: one]
[image: two]
[image: three]
[image: four]

Warning:

> keep your mind out of the gutter.

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48021/an-enigmatic-rebus-clue-twenty-five)</sub>

Comment: **Disclaimer**: I haven't hijacked Mithrandir's "Clue" series; he gave me the desired final solution in private and I constructed a puzzle around it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The cipher used is

> [Sharky's implementation of a Vigenere](https://sharkysoft.com/vigenere/) to encode textual Morse

First cipher:

> Key: [Vera](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Callahan_Full-bore_Auto-lock)
>  Vigenere: `POINTLINE`
>  Morse: A

Second cipher:

> Key: succulent (this is a cryptic: def. delicious, "suck you audibly" = succu, "fast" = Lent)
>  Vigenere: `DOTDASHDOTDOT`
>  Morse: L

Third cipher:

> Key: [Abdul](https://youtu.be/M5MnyRZLd8A?t=210)
>  Vigenere: `THREEHYPHENS`
>  Morse: O

Fourth cipher:

> Key: Aioli (another cryptic: saucy = definition; m**AI**d + h**OL**e + **I**)
>  Vigenere: `DEEOHTEA` (D-O-T)
>  Morse: E

Now we've got the answer

> ALOE (ha! Vera and succulent were even references to this answer)

Comment: "Sharky's implementation of a Vigenere" - isn't it just standard Vigenere (P+V=L, O+E=T, etc.)?

Comment: Also, how did you get the key for the second cipher?

Comment: @randal'thor I tried using `SUCK` as a key, noticed the first three letters came out as `DOT` and worked it from there.

Comment: I can't accept this unless it includes proper explanations for the 2nd and 4th keys :-)

Comment: @Will Solve it as a cryptic clue. I believe it fits somewhat.(Can't figure out the last few words)

Comment: Ha! This is almost Mithrandiresque with its blow-up encryption. Or was that a requirement for the puzzle?