# The etched words - Clue Twenty Six

Tags: visual, cryptic-clues

<sub>[<<---First clue](/q/37784)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48021/an-enigmatic-rebus-clue-twenty-five)</sub>

---

<sub>*A note from @Mithrandir: I have given explicit permission for @Khale_Kitha to post this, and gave him the answer to encode. If you want to post one, ping @Mithrandir in chat and we'll talk.*</sub>

---

The lights dim and you see, behind them, an etching on the wall that you had not noticed previously.

[image: Etched words on a wall]

You ponder what the words could mean...

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48142/the-mysterious-lines-clue-twenty-seven)</sub>

Comment: **Disclaimer**: I haven't hijacked Mithrandir's "Clue" series; he gave me the desired final solution in private and I constructed a puzzle around it.

Comment: Are the symbols at the bottom important?

Comment: They are, but it can be solved without knowing what they are.  They serve as verification of a clue.

Comment: Are they hebrew?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are

> **Calcium Carbonate**

A medicine, abbreviated calendar and a cop's criminal with verbal pause;
shortened sugar over retrograte Greek η

> η is eta
>  retrograde makes it "ate", a likely word ending; assume this is charades
>  over -> on
>  shortened sugar -> gluc? fruct?
>  verbal pause is "um" or maybe "uh" or "eh"
>  cop's criminal -> ?
>  abbreviated calendar -> cal

Taking the [cryptic-clues](/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues) at face value, it looks like

> A medicine [*def.*]; abbreviated calendar [CAL] + a cop's criminal [???] + verbal pause [UM?] + shortened sugar [GLUC?] + over [ON] + retrograde Greek η [ATE<]
>  which gives CAL???UM GLUC?ONATE

That's suggestive....

> trading out GLUC for CARB - this is definition by example, but ok -
>  and seeing the obvious missing CI in calcium, give us:
>
>  **CALCIUM CARBONATE**   (A medicine [*def.*]; abbreviated calendar [CAL] + a cop's criminal [CI]
>                      + verbal pause [UM] + shortened sugar [CARB] + over [ON]
>                       + retrograde Greek η [ATE<])
>
>  Wikipedia tells me a **confidential or criminal informant (CI)** is a thing, so that answers that too.  Yay, learning!

Comment: Calcium Carbonate works as an antacid in low doses. Though, it is hardly used by people..

Comment: on most Nutritional facts lists on food products, Sugars are under the Carbohydrate section.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, but that's not how cryptic clues work. You can say "dog" to clue "poodle", but you cannot say "poodle" to clue "dog" (at least, not without *another* hint that you're doing so).  Since all sugars are carbs, but not all carbs are sugars, you can't *just* say "sugar" to clue "carb"; this is called definition by example, and it's not deemed fair play in a cryptic.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I misread the part where you said definition by example in the answer, or I would have better implied it was a logical leap. Would that mean however that it was a minor error on the Khale's part in asking that?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> CALCIUM GLUCONATE (CAL abbreviated calendar + CI confidential informant + UM, GLUC shortened glucose + ON over + ATE eta backwards, definition 'A Medicine')

The symbols are:

> Chinese characters for 7 and 9, which is the enumeration. The sides of the polygons confirms this.

EDIT: It's since been brought to my attention that this is not the intended answer, but I fully believe it is AN answer which fully satisfies the puzzle :)

Comment: This was not the target answer, but, unfortunately, fits perfectly because I hadn't heard of a medicine by that name.