# Forget the freehand red circles - it's a freehand rebus! - Clue Twenty Eight

Tags: story, rebus

<sub>[<<---First clue](/q/37784)

[<--Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48142/the-mysterious-equations-clue-twenty-seven)</sub>

---

<sub>This is an entry in the [26th Fortnightly Topic Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/fortnightly-topic-challenge-26-rebus).</sub>

---

You speak the password. The entire space shudders, and the wall that you were leaning on open, spilling you headfirst into... an art museum? There are all of the pictures from the previous Clues there, but you ignore those. You focus on the new ones, which appear to be freehand drawn on the computer:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

You look around for a place to enter the answer. Finally, you see a door on the other side of the room, with the now-familiar keypad.

You cross the room and type in...

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51431/recondite-key-locked-another-puzzle-clue-twenty-nine)</sub>

Comment: [Freehand circles!!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta#answer-19775)

Comment: @Mithrandir **cough** still waiting **cough** :)

Comment: @Tumbler41 - one of the downsides of becoming a moderator. You have less time for other things. Don't worry, I plan on putting the next one up in the next few months :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The answer is**

> **[Tungsten.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten)**

**First**

> This looks like a smiley. So, may be it;s **STICKING TONGUE OUT**.

**Second**

> Could be **[Parseltongue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_in_Harry_Potter#Parseltongue) (Snakes language)**

**Third**

> This could be either number **10** or **[Tally Marks.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_marks)**

**So the answer is**

> [Tungsten.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten) i.e. Two tongues and a ten.

---

**OP's intended solving**

The first image

> This is indeed sticking it's tongue out. So that's *tongue*, or *tung*.

Second image

> This is a picture of a snake, with a question mark for what it says. SO that's *s*.

Third

> These are 10 tally marks, so *ten*.

All together, that's

> *tungsten*.

Comment: Wow so simple and nice answer