# Recondite key locked another puzzle... - Clue Twenty Nine!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, cryptic-clues

<sub>[<<---First clue](/q/37784)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49079/forget-the-freehand-red-circles-its-a-freehand-rebus-clue-twenty-eight)</sub>

---

<sub>*A note from @Mithrandir: I have given explicit permission for @Techidiot to post this, and gave him the answer to encode. If you want to post one, ping @Mithrandir in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) and we'll talk.*</sub>

---

The door slides open, revealing a dimly-lit - you can't see how - small room, with a short wooden desk and a plastic swivel chair. On the desk is a keypad and several pieces of paper. You pick one of them up. It appears to be a crossword:

[image]

**ACROSS**

> ```
> 1. Los Angeles, operating system(4)
> 2. Back, if around climbing unfinished odd juice(1)
> 3. Most of the men within Japanese currency(19)
> 4. Hollow, idea covering starts newly designed internet(16)
> 5. Weird, crane following after(11)
> 9. Hidden strategy, pteropodans follow!(10)
> 10. Crocodile clipped impala's ends after a time(9)
> 12. Thousand glasses cover first sample of virus(12)
> 14. Inside each puzzled trier(2)
> 15. Ring man(13)
> 16. Queen and Rook, captured aces capturing time(5)
> ```

**DOWN**

> ```
> 1. First, I became yours in chuckles without hugs(18)
> 4. It always saw left(8)
> 6. Completely empty page rust endlessly(3)
> 7. Endless tale going westwards met en route(17)
> 8. Gut less month, before unfinished trial(15)
> 9. Part of ten glands!(6)
> 11. Incomplete, army starts eliminating novices with one area(7)
> 13. Clumsy final destination, ends back(14)
> ```

*Interesting*, you think. You pick up the other papers. They appear to be the next stage of the puzzle:

**A key for the next part is lost in the crossword above..Find it and go for the next part...**

> ```
>  Nbznv. Jbvknu whtg. Jxqz - Vmpmurjz.
> ```

**And then...**

> ```
> _ _ _ _
> ```

---

<sub>[Next clue--->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51779/the-strange-phrases-clue-thirty)</sub>

Comment: [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57677/the-mystery-of-the-29th-clue) is the link to the chatroom that was used to create the puzzle - the room is frozen and deleted, so only users with 10k rep in chat can see it. The room is now in Gallery mode (anyone can enter, but only certain users can talk - before, it was in private mode (only mods and certain users).

Comment: Oh, no, some of the clues weren't [cryptic](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solutions to the clues

**ACROSS**

1. Los Angeles, operating system(4)

> LA+OS $\rightarrow$ **LAOS**

2. Back, if around climbing unfinished odd juice(1)

> F(IJ)I (Backwards *if* is *fi* around, odd *j*u*i*c*e*, unfinished *ji*, climbing *ij*) $\rightarrow$ **FIJI**

3. Most of the men within Japanese currency(19)

> YE(ME)N $\rightarrow$ **YEMEN**

4. Hollow, idea covering starts newly designed internet(16)

> I(NDI)A $\rightarrow$ **INDIA**

5. Weird, crane following after(11)

> F+RANCE $\rightarrow$ **FRANCE**

9. Hidden strategy, pteropodans follow!(10)

> strate**gy, pt**eropodans $\rightarrow$ **EGYPT**

10. Crocodile clipped impala's ends after a time(9)

> CRO+aT+IA $\rightarrow$ **CROATIA**

12. Thousand glasses cover first sample of virus(12)

> K+O(SOV)O $\rightarrow$ **KOSOVO**

14. Inside each puzzled trier(2)

> E(RITRE)A $\rightarrow$ **ERITREA**

15. Ring man(13)

> O+MAN $\rightarrow$ **OMAN**

16. Queen and Rook, captured aces capturing time(5)

> Q(A(T)A)R $\rightarrow$ **QATAR**

**DOWN**

1. First, I became yours in chuckles without hugs(18)

> L(IBY)A (Laughs-hugs=LA) $\rightarrow$ **LIBYA**

4. It always saw left(8)

> IT+ALY(always-saw) $\rightarrow$ **ITALY**

6. Completely empty page rust endlessly(3)

> CY(completely empty) + P+RUS $\rightarrow$ **CYPRUS**

7. Endless tale going westwards met en route(17)

> LAT(TAL westwards) + VIA(en route) $\rightarrow$ **LATVIA**

8. Gut less month, before unfinished trial(15)

> AUS(AUGUST-GUT) + TRIA $\rightarrow$ **AUSTRIA**

9. Part of ten glands!(6)

> t**en gland**s $\rightarrow$ **ENGLAND**

11. Incomplete, army starts eliminating novices with one area(7)

> ARM+E+N+I+A $\rightarrow$ **ARMENIA**

13. Clumsy final destination, ends back(14)

> FINLA+ND(DN back) $\rightarrow$ **FINLAND**

Here's the crossword:

> [image]

Then, taking the highlighted letters:

> In the order given by the 'enumerations' we get -
>
>  FIJI F
>  ERITREA I
>  CYPRUS R
>  LAOS S
>  QATAR T
>  ENGLAND L
>  ARMENIA E
>  ITALY T
>  CROATIA T
>  EGYPT E
>  FRANCE R
>  KOSOVO S
>  OMAN O
>  FINLAND F
>  AUSTRIA T
>  INDIA I
>  LATVIA T
>  LIBYA L
>  YEMEN E
>
>  FIRSTLETTERSOFTITLE $\rightarrow$ **FIRST LETTERS OF TITLE**

Applying that, we can get

> Using question title: RKLAP, sentence starting with *WRONG*.
>  Using Crossword title: WTTGC: *'Right. Nicely done. Next - Tqwtopng.'*

The next step is

> to visit [image: i.stack.imgur.com/Tqwto.png], recognize that this represent the [G4 Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G4_nations) (thanks @Sp3000) and take the letters at the specified points of their names. This yield the final answer - 
>
>  Brazi**l**
>  G**e**rmany
>  J**a**pan
>  In**d**ia
>
>
>  The final answer is - **LEAD**

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqwto.png

Comment: The knowledge you need is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Four) (courtesy Sp3000)

Answer (score 4):

Just getting started, it seems that

> there's a "traditional" answer to each clue that fits the crossword and is a country, but does not fit the enumeration.

ACROSS

> 1. Los Angeles, operating system(4)  **LAOS**
>  2. Back, if around climbing unfinished odd juice(1)  **FIJI**
>  3. Most of the men within Chinese currency(19)  **YEMEN**
>  4. Hollow, idea covering starts newly designed internet(16) **INDIA** (Beastly)
>  5. Weird, crane following after(11) **FRANCE**
>  9. Hidden stratEGY, PTeropodans follow!(10)   **EGPYT**
>  10. Crocodile clipped impala's ends after a time(9) **CROATIA**
>  12. Thousand glasses cover first sample of virus(12)  **KOSOVO** (I think)
>  14. Inside each puzzled trier(2)  **ERITREA**
>  15. Ring man(13) **OMAN**
>  16. Queen and Rook, captured aces capturing time(5) **QATAR**

DOWN

> 1. First, I became yours in chuckles without hugs(18)  **LIBYA**
>  4. 4. It always saw left(8) **ITALY** (Beastly)
>  6. Completely empty page rust endlessly(3)  **CYPRUS**
>  7. Endless tale going westwards met en route(17) **LATVIA** (Beastly)
>  8. Gut less month, before unfinished trial(15) **AUSTRIA** (Beastly)
>  9. Part of ten glands!(6)  **ENGLAND**
>  11. Incomplete, army starts eliminating novices with one area(7) **ARMENIA** (Beastly)
>  13. Clumsy final destination, ends back(14)  **FINLAND**

COMPLETE CROSSWORD

> [image]

Comment: Nice start. A correction - It was supposed to be *Japanese Currency* But you got it anyway. +1

Comment: You've basically got as far as I have. 'Ring man' is bugging me too though