# The strange phrases - Clue Thirty

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, steganography

<sub>[<<---First clue](/q/37784)

[<---Previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51431/recondite-key-locked-another-puzzle-clue-twenty-nine)</sub>

---

*Aha*! You think, and type in the answer. *Ding!* The pad beeps, and opens a previously-hidden drawer. Inside is what appears to be a... bunch of strange sentences, each written on a separate strip of paper, numbered one to five:

> <sup>1</sup>Yes - that is correct. Yes - I will, and that is final.

> <sup>2</sup>No - it was not her - I beg you - no!

> <sup>3</sup>After that, he decided that he would take a vacation - a *long* vacation. At a beach somewhere - perhaps Florida.

> <sup>4</sup>The man dashed through the crowd, dashing around poles, dodging people - but he could not find him!

> <sup>5</sup>What? Of course. Why not - I take offense that you think that I wouldn't!

Entirely puzzled, you sit down in the swivel chair and stare at the papers...

---

<sub>[Next clue --->](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/56258/25966)</sub>

Comment: Does "[ripped]" signify that the paper is torn at that point, or that the word "ripped" appears on the paper inside square brackets, or something else?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - that part of the paper has been ripped, and is not visible (although that's not necessary and I'm considering removing it because it's probably just going to confuse people).

Comment: Are the strips of paper in any particular order?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - yes, edited to reflect that.

Comment: ... Ah, clearly they are :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is

> Clear Morse code.

How did I get it? And What did I get?

> The first line gets us -.-.
>  The 2nd line gets us ---
>  The 3rd line gets us -.-.
>  The 4th is a tad tricky. The words "dashed" signify using dash. Hence, we get ---
>  The fifth gets us .-
>  Finally,We have -.-. --- -.-. --- .-

This gives

> **COCOA**.  Which is indeed the final answer as confirmed by the OP.

Comment: but there is only one dash on the fourth slip?

Comment: Read the lines carefully @beastly you will get your answer.

Comment: yep ffao pointed it out to me

Comment: too easy for puzzling.stackexhange :)

Comment: Mind adding some explanation of how you got the code?