# The Poetry Book - Clue Thirty-Two

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>[<<--- first clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/37784/25966)</sub>
<sub>[<--- previous clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/56258/25966)</sub>
<sub>[(?)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mwm1byZ3que1GxyHBtqNqZslFS6cssacNGRyNlQV2_k/edit)</sub>

---

"*[redacted]*," you say aloud. Nothing seems to happen. You look around the room again. Suddenly, you notice something that wasn't there before.

Sitting on the desk was a book. There was a piece of paper sticking out, marking a page.

You walk over and opened it. The book is apparently a poetry book. You glance at the page that it was open to.

> The sweltering heat exuding
>   from this quite kaleidoscopic jar
>   has made me very sweaty
>   while only barely trying

*Pretty mediocre poem*, you think to yourself.

The piece of paper that had been used a bookmark itself appeared to be a newspaper clipping. You read:

> We have records of that man that date back to when he attempted to break a wombat out of a zoo. (Why would he do that? We don't know. Really. Exactly what caused such a queer act has not yet been found, but our partner Kelly J. has conducted some research. We'll get back to you soon.)

You flip it. There was text there, too:

> Yesterday, Rep. Gary Zygatex told our reporter that he believed that this issue was of great import to the USA's jurisdictive process. He will do all he is capable of to make sure that the issue is addressed quickly.

You look back at the poetry book, to the other page that had been marked.

> i finally did it
>   but you don't know it
>   i try to tell you
>   but you don't hear
>
> i lie here
>   waiting for relief
>   the tears start to flow
>   but i keep them quiet
>
> i'll see you on the other side
>   you'll dazzle me
>   hand in hand we'll swing around
>   and laugh under the starlight
>
> we'll tell jokes as we relax
>   and pass the time together
>   wait for me there
>   until i arrive with you again

**What is all this supposed to mean?**

Comment: I'd forgotten about this, but my first reaction was "Oh my God, this is back?!"

Comment: @ThePuzzlingPlatypus - well, I didn't want to leave it unfinished ;)

Comment: Where's the next clue?

Comment: @Scratch---Cat ...it hasn't been written yet...

Comment: I'm expecting it. . . . .

Comment: @Mithrandir Please include a link to this puzzle in [that](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/56258/25966) puzzle.

Comment: @Mithrandir Where's the thirty-third?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it means

> zinc

because

> each of these blocks of text contains all letters of the alphabet except for one: we have one with no Z, one with no I, one with no N, and then one with no C.