# Help, I've gotten stuck in the Word Web!

Tags: word

<sub><sub>If you'd like to check out a similar puzzle I made, check out [The Word Web of horror - Clue Twenty Two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/47548/25966).</sub></sub>

---

Oops. You think, that after the spider invited the fly in, I'd be smart enough to stay away from the spider's house. But no. I foolishly wandered too close, and now I'm trapped here, stuck in this Word Web. However, the spider has offered to let me go if I can correctly guess her age. The problem? I don't know how long super-huge ginormous spiders live!

Luckily, she gave me a way to find out. The Word Web that I was wrapped in, she told me, would reveal the answer - I just had to find the numerical value of the final word. She also told me it was less than 50, but above 20. Can you help me find her age and get out of this mess?

---

If you haven't heard of a word web before, this is how it works. The final answer is a single word. To get to that word, you have to trace a trail back.

You start with groups of four words. Each of these four words is connected to a parent word - either in an idiom, or if they can be put together to make a different word.
For example, if you have the words SMITH, PITCH, CAT, and JACK, then those four words will lead you to BLACK.

In this case, words C3a through C3d will give you C3. C-4 will give you C. A, B, C, and D will give you the final answer - which you can then use to find her age.

---

> > A1a - BRIDGE
> >     A1b - FIRE
> >     A1c - BEAD
> >     A1d - QUICK
>
> > A2a - OVER
> >     A2b - LIGHT
> >     A2c - SHINE
> >     A2d - MAN
>
> > A3a - PILL
> >     A3b - EYE
> >     A3c - SKY
> >     A3d - COLLAR
>
> > A4a - DAISY
> >     A4b - AIR
> >     A4c - LEGS
> >     A4d - MEAT

> > B1a - HEAD
> >     B1b - BREAD
> >     B1c - EYE
> >     B1d - SLEEVE
>
> > B2a - SMALL
> >     B2b - GOOSE
> >     B2c - DOWN
> >     B2d - MOTHER
>
> > B3a - BEAT
> >     B3b - FAINT
> >     B3c - AT
> >     B3d - CHANGE
>
> > B4a - UP
> >     B4b - BABY
> >     B4c - BACK
> >     B4d - OUT

> > C1a - PAINT
> >     C1b - BED
> >     C1c - BLANKET
> >     C1d - EARS
>
> > C2a - KING
> >     C2b - QUEEN
> >     C2c - MUD
> >     C2d - HEELS
>
> > C3a - BREAD
> >     C3b - TIRE
> >     C3c - NOTE
> >     C3d - LINE
>
> > C4a - PENCE
> >     C4b - PACK
> >     C4c - TEEN
> >     C4d - SHOOTER

> > D1a - BAD
> >     D1b - DOLLAR
> >     D1c - WARRANT
> >     D1d - OFF
>
> > D2a - BULL
> >     D2b - MONEY
> >     D2c - ARM
> >     D2d - AGAINST
>
> > D3a - CUT
> >     D3b - SELL
> >     D3c - ORDER
> >     D3d - RUN
>
> > D4a - BENT
> >     D4b - AIR
> >     D4c - PLAY
> >     D4d - END

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A1: bridge, fire, bead, quick

> DRAW. (Drawbridge, draw fire, draw a bead on ..., quick on the draw.)

A2: over, light, shine, man

> MOON. (Moon over an unattainable beloved, moonlight, moonshine, man in the moon.)

A3: pill, eye, sky, collar

> BLUE. (Blue pill in *The Matrix* or, bleh, Viagra; blue eyes; blue sky; blue-collar workers.)

A4: daisy, air, legs, meat

> FRESH. (Fresh as a daisy, fresh air, fresh legs, fresh meat.)

So A is

> DRAW, MOON, BLUE, FRESH -> **BLOOD**. (Draw blood, blood moon, blue blood, fresh blood.)

B1: head, bread, eye, sleeve

> ROLL. (Heads will roll, bread roll, roll one's eyes, roll up one's sleeves.)

B2: small, goose, down, mother

> STEP. (One small step ..., goose-step, step down, stepmother.)

B3: beat, faint, at, change

> HEART. (Heartbeat, faint at heart, (merely) at heart, change of heart.)

B4: up, baby, back, out

> Actually, STEP would go nicely here too! Step up, baby steps, step back, step out. But it seems like a more solid fit for B2. I wondered about FACE but wasn't satisfied and OP indicates in comments that it's wrong. Alconja, in comments, suggests an answer that's pretty clearly right: THROW. (Throw up, throw the baby out with the bathwater, throwback, throw out.)

So B is

> ROLL, STEP, HEART, THROW ... and Alconja continues to be helpful by suggesting STONE. (Rolling stone, stepping stone, heart of stone, throw stones at.)

C1: paint, bed, blanket, ears

> WET. (Wet paint, wet the bed, wet blanket, wet behind the ears.)

C2: king, queen, mud, heels

> In the light of Mithrandir's hint I think this must be DRAG. (A drag queen is a man dressed as a woman for a certain kind of performance; apparently, though I hadn't known, there are also drag *kings*. One can drag another (or their reputation) through the mud, and drag one's heels.)

C3: bread, tire, note, line

> FLAT. (Flatbread, flat tire, flat note, flatline.)

C4: pence, pack, teen, shooter

> SIX. (Sixpence, six-pack, sixteen, six-shooter.)

So C is

> WET, DRAG, FLAT, SIX -> **FEET**. (Wet feet, drag one's feet, flat feet, six feet under.)

D1: bad, dollar, warrant, off

> SIGN. (A bad sign; \$; sign one's death/arrest warrant; sign off.)

D2: bull, money, arm, against

> PIT. (Pit bull terrier, money pit, armpit, pit X against Y.)

D3: cut, sell, order, run

> SHORT. (Cut short, sell short, in short order, run short.)

D4: bent, air, play, end

> I wondered about LINE, but wasn't surprised that OP indicated that was wrong. Probably (in view of his hint in comments) this is DEAD. (Dead bent, dead air, play dead, dead end. Though I don't find "dead bent" entirely convincing.)

So D is

> SIGN, PIT, SHORT, DEAD -> **STOP**. (Stop sign, pit stop, stop short, stop dead.)

And so, finally, we have

> BLOOD, STONE, FEET, STOP -> ?

which clearly leads to

> COLD. It seems (thanks to user ablerks for suggesting this in another answer) that the intended way to get from there to an age is just to convert letters to numbers via A1Z26 and add 'em up. So our spider is 3+15+12+4=**34** years old.

Comment: A2 or simply over the moon

Comment: Group B could be OUT (roll out [of the shop/the red carpet/autobots], step out[side/for a moment], [eat your] heart out, ...), which fits your meta theory nicely with "out cold".

Comment: Almost everything here is correct; D4 isn't, but you seem to have gotten D even so :) Your tenuous guess is not the answer for B4. As for how to get the age... I'll let you stew for a bit on that.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Ah yes, now that I think about it that's probably what I first thought of. (I added the explanations after posting the answer.)

Comment: @Alconja I think it shouldn't be, because OUT is in list B4 and these puzzles generally avoid that sort of repetition. I think.

Comment: Good point (teach me for not looking at B4). Updated guesses: B4 => THROW (throw up, throw the baby out with the bath water?, throwback, throw out), making B => STONE (rolling stone gathers no moss, stepping stone, heart of stone, stone's throw away). And stone cold obviously still fits the final too.

Comment: That all sounds _extremely_ plausible, and I have other reasons for thinking THROW is likely (some comments made by Mithrandir in TSL).

Comment: Here's a hint for the one you couldn't get - the phrase with heels is reluctant.

Comment: OK, C2 done then. Still not very confident about D4, but everything else seems solid.

Comment: (D4 isn't correct, just to confirm. Think opossums.)

Comment: Ta. Perhaps I've got it dead right now.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Gareth's answer:
This might be too simple but might the age just be

> the sum of the numerical values in the alphabet of COLD? C-3 + O-15 + L-12 + D-4 = 34

Comment: It's certainly possible... ;)

Comment: Bleh. OK, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Also adding to Gareth's answer
The answer for C2 might be

> HIGH (High king, High queen, High mud?, High heels). For FEET it can be High [arched] feet

Comment: Nice idea, but unfortunately not - I think the one I have in mind fits a tad better.